# Chrome blurs div when clicked upon

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

We've come across something strange while developing [our site](http://bit.ly/Noz3gV). We have a collection of divs on the screen similar to Pinterest. When any of the divs gets clicked, the content of that div gets loaded in an iframe on the right. The problem is that in Chrome, when a div gets clicked, everything in that div (image, text) blurs until the mouse is moved away from the div. Any idea what can be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `spring` CSS class is being applied when you click, and removed when "moused out".

[image]